# Duplicate variable names in switch/case

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Recently started using EcmaScript 6 / 2015 and having my code transpiled with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). I'm also using [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), so writing a *reducer* that looks like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION1:
      const myvar = ''; // do something to determine myvar
      return { ...state, myvar };
    case ACTION2:
      const myvar = ''; // do something to determine myvar
      return { ...state, myvar };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20reducer%20%3D%20(state%2C%20action)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20case%20ACTION1%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20myvar%20%3D%20%27%27%3B%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%20to%20determine%20myvar%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20...state%2C%20myvar%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20case%20ACTION2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20myvar%20%3D%20%27%27%3B%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%20to%20determine%20myvar%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20...state%2C%20myvar%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B)

Obviously the real thing does more advanced things, this just illustrates the idea. My `.babelrc` contains:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Now, Babel tells me:

> Duplicate declaration "myvar"

I don't understand. I thought that both `case` blocks would create a different scope, and thus re-using variable names for whatever reason would be allowed. Is my expectation wrong, or is this indeed supposed to work in EcmaScript 6 / 2015 and is it some kind of bug?

Comment: No braces - no block - no scope :-)

Comment: D'oh... Thanks! Feel free to add it as an answer ;)